# How to download bower packages in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Our ASP.NET Core 2.0 project has been created in Visual Studio 2017. We use Visual Studio online for code check-ins. The directory that is never checked-in is `wwwroot\lib`. It contains bower packages such as bootstrap, etc.

I am now trying to open this project from Visual Studio Code on Linux.  The project loads fine and creates a `launch.json` file automatically. Nuget packages also seem to be downloaded automatically. However, bower packages do not get downloaded.

I  installed Bower extension (by Don Jayamanne) and tried `bower update` from the command editor. Although it seems to succeed, I do not see any bootstrap files downloaded.

How do I get all the bower packages installed?

Also, when I look at `bower.json,` there is no hint that the files must be downloaded into `wwwroot/lib` directory. How does the system figure this out?

Finally, a slightly unrelated question. Under VS 2017, `wwwroot` is automatically treated as the root directory when launching the debugger. Does Visual Studio Code automatically do the same? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help.

My project is about the same as yours. In Windows 10, I use Visual Studio 2017 to start a dot net core 2.0 project. I have a virtual machine running Linux Mint with Visual Studio Code. I do not move the project from Windows to Linux, but recreate it there.

Anyway, I install Bower at the terminal (re: [Using Bower](http://blog.osmosys.asia/2015/06/08/using-bower-grunt-and-vs-code-for-node-js-development/)). At the same time, I install both `Bower` and `Bower package watcher` right inside Visual Studio Code. (I think one really needs these two inside the VS Code *and* no need to have it in installed at the terminal.)

If you install only the Extensions, in VSCode press F1. Type 'Bower' (Please note the word starts with an upper case). Then a list will come out. Select 'Bower Update'. Then automatic download will occur.

If you install Bower at the terminal, launch a terminal. Change directory to the directory where your project is. Type 'bower update'. (Please note the bower does not start with an upcase.) Download will occur.

A word about where bower download package:
If you have a wwwroot directory, dot net core assumes files will be served from within this directory. To use the bower package, add a file called `.bowerrc` beside `bower.json` and enter the following:

```
{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```